# Simple CRUD with Scala and Playframework

Tags: json, mongodb, scala, playframework

Technology stack: Scala, PlayFramework 2.3.8, MongoDB ( Salat + casbah ).

I am developing some restful APIs, with simple CRUD.

The entity:

```
case class Company(
_id: ObjectId = new ObjectId,
user_id: Any = "",
cinema_id: Int = 0,
name: String = "",
status: String = "",
releaseId: Int, fileId: Int,
date: CompanyDate,
showTime: List[Int] = List())

case class CompanyDate(start: DateTime, end: DateTime)
```

I create Reads for creating the object from JSON:

```
    def createFromJson(json: JsValue, user: User): Reads[Company] = {
    val user_id = (for {
        cinema_id <- (json \ "cinema_id").asOpt[Int]
        cinema <- user.cinema.find(_.id == cinema_id)
    } yield cinema.getUser(user._id.toString)
        ).getOrElse(0)

    (
        Reads.pure(new ObjectId) and
            Reads.pure[Any](user_id).filter(ValidationError("You have no access to this cinema"))(_ != 0) and
            (__ \ "cinema_id").read[Int] and
            (__ \ "name").read[String](minLength[String](1) keepAnd maxLength[String](100)) and
            Reads.pure[String]("new") and
            (__ \ "release_id").read[Int] and
            (__ \ "file_id").read[Int] and
            (__ \ "date").read[CompanyDate] and
            (__ \ "show_time").read[List[Int]](minLength[List[Int]](1))
        )(Company.apply _).flatMap(company => Reads { _ =>
        if (company.date.start isAfter company.date.end) {
            JsError(JsPath \ "date" \ "start" -> ValidationError("Start < end"))
        } else {
            JsSuccess(company)
        }
    })
}
```

It took me create wrapped function to pass user to Reads, because some field ( user_id ) calculate from current user - client doesn't know this information.
It looks a little ugly, but works ok.

The Controller for create action is very simple, it takes json, casts it to class and saves to DB.

Next thing: Update. In update method i want reuse some validation cases ( check date.start < date.end, e.g. ), but i don't receive the full object. My client only sends me changed fields.

Some fields ( cinema_id and user_id ) can only be set when creating object, they can't be updated.

Example request (**UPDATED**):

```
    PUT /api/company/1
    {
      "name": "Name",
      "status": "delete"
    }
```

How can i validate this json and update existing object?

What is the best approach to solve this task?

Comment: Can you clarify what you are after - it's not that clear what you are asking.

Comment: One approach would be to use your controller to find the company object by name (say method `Company.findByName(name:String):Option[Company]`) then if the user is allowed to update the company, and the validation is successful, then go ahead with the update (say method `Company.update(company:Company):...`), but hard to tell exactly what you are after.

Comment: Ok, try to explain. PUT request - from URL i know Company.id, from body - i got json with 2 fields ( example above ). I made select query to MongoDB and gotten Company object. Its clear. Now i have 2 problems - validate json ( e.g. field "name" must be less 100 chars length) and update the object.

Comment: If you plan to do a JSON/MongoDB coast-to-coast API, you can have a look at http://mandubian.com/2013/01/13/JSON-Coast-to-Coast/

Comment: Have you implemented CORS already?